# Pour over coffee : what is needed for a good pitcher replacement?

Tags: coffee

My pourover coffee pitcher just broke. Its the second time it does this this year, so i guess the maker of this pourover kit is making flimsy glass for their pitchers.

[image]

So is there a good replacement for those kinds of pitchers? What is important in a replacement? Does the mouth of the pitcher need to contain the whole filter? Do the sides really need to follow the filter?

Here is how the filter looks like
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of pour-over coffee funnels with a flared bottom so the funnel can sit on top of a normal pitcher, carafe or coffee cup.

[image]

So presumably the pitcher doesn't need to cover the sides of the funnel. Try using a mason jar or any similar heat-resistant container that the funnel fits into the mouth of. If you don't notice any flavor difference, then you know you don't need the glass sides.

There are also pour-over sets that use a stand to hold the funnel, for example:

[image]

You could probably improvise a stand. All it really needs is a ring for the funnel to sit in, and a stand to hold the ring the proper height over your pitcher or carafe. An erlenmeyer flask stand or a tripod  for using over a bunsen burner would work, eg

[image] ([This one](https://www.homesciencetools.com/product/tripod-burner-stand-5-inch/) is only 5" tall which might be a bit short, but taller ones are available.)

As moscafj pointed out, some carafes are made of boro-silicate glass so they can be used on the stovetop. If that is your intended use, be sure that your substitute carafe is stovetop-safe.

Comment: Chemex brand carafes are made from borosillicate glass, which allows them to be placed on a stove burner over low heat.  If this is your practice, be sure to find a container that will be safe for this application.

Comment: If anybody lands on this question, here is what I did to fix my problem: I found a caraphe at Ikea  that has the exact same size than my filter. So I guess if most filters have about the same diameter, it should fit for you too. https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/p/ikea-365-pitcher-with-lid-clear-glass-cork-50279721/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=surfaces&utm_campaign=shopping_feed&utm_content=free_google_shopping_clicks_Eating&gclid=Cj0KCQiAkNiMBhCxARIsAIDDKNWlX9eSY11LDAE1hWCC-PmMEilKngDR_oMK-Q4P3AZodDRRFHl6RRYaAtO3EALw_wcB